# Simplest way to make a device find each other in the network (find its IP) C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, broadcast

I need a device to send a broadcast and receive the IP of the other device that will be waiting to respond.

I runned through this code

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping p = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply rep = p.Send("192.168.1.1");
if (rep.Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
{
    //host is active
}
```

But it is slow and returns me any device in the network not the one i want.

Should i create a UDP server that will wait for a broadcast signal and then send its IP to the client that sent the broadcast?

Comment: Instead of send the specific Ping message, just send a UDP custom "ping" and respond with a custom "ping-reply".

Comment: I pretty much answer the exact same question in detail in the question "[Finding open TCP port in a network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104215/finding-open-tcp-port-in-a-network)"

Comment: I will have two devices running the same app, this app will have 2 btns one that will "start receiving" and the one that will "send the signal" so i get who is receiving. No data transfer needed i just need to ping and get who is running on some port like 3000. Am i able to do that with the example above? I'm kind of new to this connection stuff so help  :c

Answer (score 0):

With just pinging the IP it is difficult to confirm it is your device.

If you do an extra validation / handshake with a custom message through a TCP or UDP connection that will help you confirm it is your device and also give you opportunity to pass additional configuration information about the client device found on the network.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution if you are using Xamarin.iOS is to use [Apple Bonjour](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and if you are on Xamarin.Android you could use [bonjour.net](https://github.com/automaters/bonjour.net) or Android [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html)